# Binding click and keyevents in android

Tags: java, android, keyevent

What I want to do is to call click() action when a specific Key Event fired. I can handle the keydown event for a specific object but what if there are 2 different clickable object ( say one is a picture and the other is a button and click actions behaves different).

So I just want to catch the event and then let android behave as clicked ( not key down ).

thanks

Edit :

I find  the solution finally.

steps for it :

-implement onKeyListener
-call the performClick() method of the object that is asubclass of view and you want to call the onclick.

Sample Code :

```
button.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            view.performClick();
            Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    "button onkey - " + i,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            return false; //return true if you want to stop the rest of same key event processing.
}
```

I am afraid of to forget writing the solution later. I just write for a few hours. Then I will get the answer to a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question. Do you want to only capture the event or do you want to do something when a user clicks a `View`? Here's how you can do it, if it's the latter...

`OnClickListener()`

**Example:**

```
private Button btn;
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      // Handle your click events here
   }
});
```

Just do the same with the `ImageView`.

**Documentation:**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

Comment: So what will I call in 

`public boolean onKeyDown ( int keyKode, KeyEvent event ) {

...

}`

I need to set the activity like clicked on screen. I need to call activity's click action. not an object's.

Comment: It is possible to create an OnClickListener() for the entire Activity, by implementing View.OnClickListener. Still not sure if that's what you're looking for...

Comment: I think I found the way I will follow. I need to implement object's onKeyListener to call `performClick();`